# What to do next with Mercurial after I install it in my PC?

Tags: mercurial

I have downloaded and installed Mercurial in my PC.
However, I don't know what to do next. I thought it's like other programs; that after installing it'll just appear and then you can already use it. What am I do next?

Answer (score 10):

Try Joel Spolsky's great Mercurial tutorial at : [Hg Init: a Mercurial tutorial](http://hginit.com)
It's the most lucid explanation of Mercurial I've ever come across. You'll have a very good idea what to do next after reading it.

Comment: Definitely. That's the first thing that came to my mind after reading the question.

Answer (score 9):

Mercurial is driven from the command line, so you would normally open a terminal to use it. However, if you would be more comfortable with a GUI, take a look at [TortoiseHg](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/TortoiseHg). You can find tutorials, quick-start guides and other Mercurial documentation at the [Mercurial](http://mercurial.selenic.com/) site.